# error while querying Solr : Failed to query Solr using '(**)': [Reason: undefined field django_ct]

Tags: django, solr, solr5

I am very new to solr and was trying to implement using examples in the official quick start guide.
here are the steps i took

1. bin/solr start -e cloud -noprompt
2. bin/post -c gettingstarted example/exampledocs/schema.xml

here is the error log

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field django_ct
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getDynamicFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1298)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$SolrQueryAnalyzer.getWrappedAnalyzer(IndexSchema.java:444)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.DelegatingAnalyzerWrapper$DelegatingReuseStrategy.getReusableComponents(DelegatingAnalyzerWrapper.java:74)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.tokenStream(Analyzer.java:172)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.QueryBuilder.createFieldQuery(QueryBuilder.java:199)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.newFieldQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:370)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.getFieldQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:753)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.handleBareTokenQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:537)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:299)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:185)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:107)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:189)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:107)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:96)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.parse(SolrQueryParserBase.java:151)
    at org.apache.solr.search.LuceneQParser.parse(LuceneQParser.java:50)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:141)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:203)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:229)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:143)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2064)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:654)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:450)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:227)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with where I kept my schema file. The quick star guide is really not particular about it and most tutorials dont cover 5.2.
The schema file has to be put inside the 'conf' folder.